# Function to transform 3d points to a new coordinate system with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, 3d, geometry

I have `n` points in space:
`points.shape == (n,3)`

I have a new coordinate system defined by a point `O = [ox, oy, oz]` and 3 orthogonal vectors of different lengths: `Ox = [oxx, oxy, oxz], Oy = [oyx, oyy, oyz], Oz = [ozx, ozy, ozz]`.

How can I write a function like that?

```
def change_coord_system(points, O, Ox, Oy, Oz)
    return # points in new coordinate system
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 4 non-coplanar points in original system (where `lx` is length of the first vector and so on):

```
(0,0,0), (lx,0,0), (0,ly,0), (0,0,lz)
```

and their twins in new system

```
 [ox, oy, oz]
 [oxx + ox, oxy + oy, oxz + oz]
 [oyx + ox, oyy + oy, oyz + oz]
 [ozx + ox, ozy + oy, ozz + oz]
```

Affine transformation matrix A should transform initial points into their pair points

```
   A * P = P'
```

make matrix with point column vectors:

```
      |x1  x2  x3  x4|    |x1' x2' x3' x4'|
   A *|y1  y2  y3  y4| =  |y1' y2' y3' y4'|  
      |z1  z2  z3  z4|    |z1' z2' z3' z4'|
      |1   1   1    1|    |1   1    1    1|

      |0  lx  0  0|    |ox oxx + ox . .|
   A *|0  0  ly  0| =  |oy oxy + oy . .| // lazy to make last columns  
      |0  0  0  lz|    |oz oxz + oz . .|
      |1  1  1   1|    |1   1    1    1|
```

To calculate A, it is needed to multiply both sudes by inverse of P matrix

```
A * P * P-1 = P' * Pinverse
A * E = P' * Pinverse
A = P' * Pinverse
```

So calculate inverse matrix for P and multiply it with right-side matrix.

Edit: inverse matrix calculated by Maple is

```
 [[-1/lx, -1/ly, -1/lz, 1], 
  [1/lx, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 1/ly, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 1/lz, 0]]
```

And resulting affine transformation matrix is

```
[[-ox/lx+(oxx+ox)/lx, -ox/ly+(oyx+ox)/ly, -ox/lz+(ozx+ox)/lz, ox],
 [-oy/lx+(oxy+oy)/lx, -oy/ly+(oyy+oy)/ly, -oy/lz+(ozy+oy)/lz, oy], 
 [-oz/lx+(oxz+oz)/lx, -oz/ly+(oyz+oz)/ly, -oz/lz+(ozz+oz)/lz, oz], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

[Maple sheet view for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z713j.jpg)

**Edit:**
Just have noticed: Maple did not remove excessive summands, so result should be simpler:

```
[[(oxx)/lx, (oyx)/ly, (ozx)/lz, ox],
 [(oxy)/lx, (oyy)/ly, (ozy)/lz, oy], 
 [(oxz)/lx, (oyz)/ly, (ozz)/lz, oz], 
 [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have two points, `P=[2, 4, 5]` and `Q=[7, 2, 5]`. First you have to find the matrix for the rotation transformation **A** and the matrix **B** for transport and apply the below equation

[image]

The code using numpy is

```
import numpy as np
# points P and Q
points = np.array([[2,4,5], [7,2,5]])

# suppose that the matrices are
rotation_matrix = np.matrix('1 2 1; 1 2 1; 1 2 1')
b = np.array([1, 1, 1])

def transformation(points, rotation_matrix, b):
    for n in range(points.shape[0]):
    points[n,0] = rotation_matrix[0,0] * points[n, 0] + rotation_matrix[0,1] * points[n, 1] + rotation_matrix[0,2] * points[n, 2] + b[0]
    points[n,1] = rotation_matrix[1,0] * points[n, 0] + rotation_matrix[1,1] * points[n, 1] + rotation_matrix[1,2] * points[n, 2] + b[1]
    points[n,2] = rotation_matrix[2,0] * points[n, 0] + rotation_matrix[2,1] * points[n, 1] + rotation_matrix[2,2] * points[n, 2] + b[2]


Output:  array([[16, 30, 82],
                [17, 27, 77]])
```

I think that the above function gives the new points. You can check it. Of course, you can perform matrix multiplication with numpy although, you need to reshape the np.arrays.

Comment: Thanks, but could you provide an implementation with the proposed signature, i.e.

change_coord_system(points, O, Ox, Oy, Oz) => points in new coordinate system

Comment: @Bolo This is mathematical question and not programming! You have to find the rotational matrix from Ox, Oy, Oz and construct it inside the function, if you want this function signature. If you do not give me more details, I cannot help.

Comment: Sorry but I think you have enough details to implement the function which will indeed compute the rotation matrix.