# Put sin on segment in 3d

Tags: python, java, c++, math, 3d

i need to put a sin function, or any other function on start of segment in 3d space.
Something like that:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWk51.png)

But in 3d space, help me pls, i spent about 4 days for solving it, but did not get  result

There are 2 points in space at arbitrary positions. I need a sinusoid between these two arbitrary points.

[3d segment example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SMMN.png)

[An example of the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siTv2.png)

Comment: Do you want this in a specific programming language? Can you plot a line segment in that language, at least as a starting point?

Comment: @doctorlove preffered languages are python/java/c/c++. Can you use https://www.geogebra.org/calculator for plotting? This solution will be used for proprietary software

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add appropriate tags (language, environment) and also include how you are intending to define _where_ in space is the curve going to be added. Also what does it mean to add a curve? Do you have a curve class, or a series of points, or explain how a curve might be defined in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate point set in OXY plane and apply affine transformation to make OX axis coincide with desired vector, also you need to define one normal vector to get sin plane unambiguously.

[Math for affine matrix calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327129/function-to-transform-3d-points-to-a-new-coordinate-system-with-numpy/55335897#55335897) (here simpler because we can choose unit-length vectors)